# imread octave to imread cv2

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, octave

I have to translate a code from Octave to Python, among many things the program does something like this:

load_image = imread('image.bmp')

which as you can see its a bitmap, then if I do

size(load_image) that prints (1200,1600,3) which its ok, but, when I do:

load_image

it prints a one dimensional array, that does not make any sense to me, my question is how in Octave are these values interpreted because I have to load the same image in opencv and I couldn't find the way.

thanks.

Comment: What version of octave are you using? Can you provide a link to your bmp?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a 3D array in octave. Here in the x-dimension you seem to have RGB values for each pixel and Y and Z dimension are the rows and columns respectively. However when you print it you will see all the values in the array and hence it looks like a 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and look at the output:

```
load_image(:,:,i)
```

The i stands for the dimensions of your image RGB. If you want to 2D print your 3D image using matplotlib or similar, you need to do the same.